# goquery: stop parsing when another element is reached

Tags: go, goquery

Suppose I have this HTML page. I want to parse it using [Go](https://golang.org/) and [goquery](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery):

```
<html>
    <head><!--Page header stuff--></head>
    <body>
         <h1 class="h1-class">Heading 1</h1>
             <div class="div-class">Stuff1</div>
             <div class="div-class">Stuff2</div>
         <h1 class="h1-class">Heading 2</h1>
             <div class="div-class">Stuff3</div>
             <div class="div-class">Stuff4</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As it happens, I'd like only to get those DIVs before Heading 2 and skip the rest. This code works great to get *all* DIVs:

```
 doc := GetGoQueryDocument(url) //Defined elsewhere
 doc.Find("div.div-class").Each(func(_ int, theDiv *goquery.Selection){
     //do stuff with each theDiv
     //The problem is that it finds div.div-class elements below Heading 2.
     //I want to skip those.
 })
```

Is there any way to tell goquery to skip elements located beneath a certain tag and classname? Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, actually pretty easy:

```
doc.Find(".h1-class").First().NextUntil(".h1-class")
```

I would recommend you read through the godoc: https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery

It explains all of the different ways you can manipulate the selection.